Añadir imagen a tabla a jsPDF
Estoy creando una tabla con jsPDF y HTML, todo sale bien menos el mostrar las imagenes en el pdf.
 <table class="table table-bordered" id="tabla">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">
                <b>Mes Evaluado:</b> Enero<br>
                <b>Auditoria:</b> Supervisor<br>
                <b>Sucursal:Prueba1<br>
            </td>
        </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                Categoria 1
                  </th>

                    <th colspan=3 style="text-align:center">
                    Calificación Categoria: 10
                    </th>
                </tr>
                
                <tr>
                    <th>Descripcion</th>
                    <th style="text-align:center">Calificación</th>
                    <th style="text-align:center">Nota</th>
                    <th style="text-align:center">Foto</th>
                </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            100
                        </td>

                        <td style="text-align:center">
                             Nota de Prueba
                        </td>

                       <td style="text-align:center; width: 200px; height: 200px;">
                             <img style="width: 200px" src='img/img.jpg/>
                      </td>
                 </tr>
        </table>

Como ven aquí al final trato de añadir una imagen, en el código html si me lo muestra pero al hacer la importacion a PDF no me muestra la imagen.
Aquí les dejo el código js:


    $('#buttonPDF').click(function () {
        var doc = new jsPDF()
        doc.autoTable({ html: '#tabla' })
        doc.save('table.pdf')
    });




Una opción sencilla que encontré fue en vez de convertirlo directamente a PDF, lo mandé a imprimir y de ahí ya lo guarde como PDF, el código que utilicé fue el siguiente:


  function printDiv(nombreDiv) {
    var contenido = document.getElementById(nombreDiv).innerHTML;
    var contenidoOriginal = document.body.innerHTML;

    document.body.innerHTML = contenido;
    window.print();
    document.body.innerHTML = contenidoOriginal;


  }
    <!-- añadi boton en html que me mande a la función en js para imprimir -->
    <a href="#" title="Imprimir" onclick="printDiv('areaImprimir')" value="imprimir div"><i
    class="fas fa-print fa-2x" style="color: #1095A1">&nbsp;&nbsp;</i></a>



Sólo añadí una etiqueta div a la tabla con el id area imprimir:
    <div class="table-responsive tblcenter" id="areaImprimir" style="width:55%;">
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="tabla">

obviamente hay que carrarla despues de que cierras el table.
